# How to open a new tab in IE when Edge is the default browser with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, internet-explorer

With reference to [this script](https://superuser.com/a/877249/220023), how can I open IE instead of Edge using PowerShell on Windows 10 when Edge is the default browser?

Comment: Just run iexplore.exe http://website.com. Windows will know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check if an IE instance is already started. If not, create one via COM. Otherwise select the Shell Window of the running IE (this can be a difficult) and open your URL in a new tab in the background.

```
# Set BrowserNavConstants to open URL in new tab
# Full list of BrowserNavConstants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360.aspx
$navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;

$ie = $null
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    #Write-Output "IE is running"
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }
    sleep -milliseconds 50
    $ie.Navigate2("http://google.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    sleep -milliseconds 50
    $ie.visible=$true
    $ie.Navigate("http://google.com");
}

# Cleanup
'ie' | ForEach-Object {Remove-Variable $_ -Force}
```